# PHP Custom Variables For IPN

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

Ok so I'm sure a lot of people have already asked this, yet I have not seen any real clear answers.  I need to capture a variable that I already have a value for....here is my example:

```
<?php

$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dreams`") or die(mysql_error());

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $info['first']; ?> <?php echo $info['last']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['city']; ?> <?php echo $info['state']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['dream']; ?></td>
            <td>$<?php echo $info['donation_goal']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2HGLK2WGELUNG">
****************<input type="hidden" name="dream_id" value="<?php echo $info['dream_id']; ?>">
                <input type="image" src="images/donatebutton.png" id="donate" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table
}
```

This shows as this:

http://www.dreamsurreal.com/images/example.jpg

The line with all of the ******** in it is where I'm having trouble.

I created the button in paypal.com but I added the ******* line in myself.

I need this variable to be passed to paypal so that I when my database is updated through ipn.php.  Here is the MYSQL update area for ipn.php:

```
// add this order to a table of completed orders
    $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
    $mc_gross = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
    $dream_id = $_POST['dream_id'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
            (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$mc_gross', '$dream_id')";
```

But for some reason even though I added the $dream_id = $_POST['dream_id'] and also added $dream_id into the INSERT part of the mysql insert, it doesn't insert the actual variable, it just makes it 0.

I hope I made this clear enough for everyone, could I please get a bit of help on how to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working everyone....ok so here is how its done:

Here is our button script without the added variable....

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2HGLK2WGELUNG">
    <input type="image" src="images/donatebutton.png" id="donate" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Add this line into our form....

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $MY_VARIABLE; ?>">
```

Replace the $MY_VARIABLE with your own variable.

Our new code for our button will look like

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2HGLK2WGELUNG">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $MY_VARIABLE; ?>">
    <input type="image" src="images/donatebutton.png" id="donate" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

After that, in your ipn.php change this area

```
// add this order to a table of completed orders
    $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
    $mc_gross = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
            (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$mc_gross')";
```

Add these into it (I'm using an integer so I'm just making sure its the right type)

```
$MY_VARIABLE = (int)$_POST['item_number'];
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
    (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$mc_gross', '$MY_VARIABLE')";
```

After all of our fixes, this entire area should look like this:

```
    // add this order to a table of completed orders
    $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
    $mc_gross = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
    $dream_id = (int)$_POST['item_number'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
            (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$mc_gross', '$dream_id')";
```

I hope this all helps, thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok....so this worked for the sandbox....now I am having trouble with the live version of it....grrrr....lol.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$dream_id = $_POST['dream_id'];
```

to

```
$dream_id = (int)$_POST['dream_id'];
```

If you look closely (and if I remember correctly) there's a dot at the end of PayPal's custom value field. Typecasting the variable to an integer fixes this problem as well as protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can read more on typecasting in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Do I have to add dream_id under custom variables while creating the button or am I able to just add it to the coding myself like I mentioned above?  But yes, I will change that as well to cast it as an integer, thank you.

Comment: Just changing the line of your code should be fine. I don't do a lot of stuff in PayPal itself so there might be some kind of setting or configuration I don't know about to fix this.